# In OSMnx, how would I set all roads to be two-way roads?

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

In fact it is as the title state.
I want to test my simulation model on a simplified version, which means less roads so I took only the driving roads, but some of them are one-way roads.
**How would I set all roads in a graph to be of two-way?**

For example this is the graph that I work with:

```
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(35.00843, 34.99174, 135.78775, 135.77495, network_type='drive')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils_graph.get_undirected). The `get_undirected` function converts a directed multigraph to an undirected multigraph.